# Java - parsing text using delimiter for separating different arguments

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, delimiter

How would you use multiple delimiters or a single delimiter to detect and separate out different string matches?

For example, I use a `Scanner` to parse in the following string:

> MrsMarple=new Person(); MrsMarple.age=30;

I would like to separate out this string to determine, in sequence, when a new person is being created and when their age is being set. I also need to know what the age is being set to.

There can be anything between and/or either side of these arguments (there doesn't necessarily have to be a space between them, but the semi-colon is required). The "MrsMarple" could be any word. I would also prefer any arguments following a "//" (two slashes) on the same line to be ignored but that's optional.

If you can think of a simple alternative to using regex I'm more than willing to consider it.

Comment: You want to write Java interpreter?

Comment: only for a couple of specific java commands. It's just easier this way for what I'm doing (visual polygon editor, to aid in the making of hard-coded polygons for 2d graphics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might try a simple split/loop approach.

Given `String input = "MrsMarple=new Person(); MrsMarple.age=30;"`:

```
String[] noComments = input.split("//");
String[] statements = input.split(noComments[0]);
for(String statement: statements) {
    String[] varValue = statement.split("=");
    ...
    // Additional MrsMarple-SmartSense Technology (tm) here...
    ...
}
```

with judicious use of `String.trim()` and or other simple tools.

Comment: Allowing spaces in a more complex command makes this approach a bit more challenging. "poly.addPoint(4,3);". I already have the regex for the commands separately which is why I was asking for a solution involving it. But I will go with this solution if regex is out of the question in this case.

Comment: You have answered it for me actually. I'm going use this approach to separate them out, then the regex to retrieve the values. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Or to make the the matter more general (and without regexes), you may try scripting (as it looks like a script language syntax): http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/ . Example:

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String input = "MrsMarple=new Person(); MrsMarple.age=30;"
try {
  jsEngine.eval(input);
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this case you'll need a Java class called Person with public field called age. Above code has not been tested, you may need to add something like

```
jsEngine.eval("importPackage(my.package);");
```

to make it work. Anyway, Oracle's tutorial should be helpfull.

Comment: Yes, I can see this approach working too. Handy to know you can get a javascript eval function in java.

Comment: Now that's slick.  From the link provided: "Currently, Rhino is the only engine included in the core JDK 6 libraries, although it is not dictated by the platform"; and Rhino is a JavaScript engine.